# How to set a Property (i.e. through BeanUtils) without knowing it's type

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans, apache-commons-beanutils

I need to set some properties of a JavaBean. I have a generic `Map<String, String>` where the first String is the **Name** of the property and the second one represents it's value.

Now if the map looks like this:

```
"greeting" : "Hello"
"cool" : "true"
"amount" : "42"
```

and my setters in the bean look like this:

```
public void setGreeting(String greeting);
public void setCool(boolean cool);
public void setAmount(int amount);
```

i need to set these properties generically like:

```
BeanUtils.setProperty(myBean, "amount", myMap.get("amount"));
```

so that BeanUtils finds the right method to use and converts the String to the right type. At most places in the API doc it says "No type conversion" but i found a lot of converters in the API doc so i assume that there must be a way of doing this.

How can i let BeanUtils find the right method without knowing its type?

Comment: Did you try it? Looks like there is type conversion http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/api/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#setProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) says:

> Set the specified property value, performing type conversions as required to conform to the type of the destination property.

So it should convert your values automatically.

Comment: Okay thanks... i actually already found this sentence in the documentation but somehow i read "performing type conversions **is** required to conform..." just one single character that completely inverts the meaning..

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of class [`ConvertUtilsBean`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/api/index.html), the types that you can convert from `String` or `String[]` to the destination type automatically are:

- `java.lang.BigDecimal` (no default value)
- `java.lang.BigInteger` (no default value)
- `boolean and java.lang.Boolean` (default to false)
- `byte and java.lang.Byte` (default to zero)
- `char and java.lang.Character` (default to a space)
- `java.lang.Class` (no default value)
- `double and java.lang.Double` (default to zero)
- `float and java.lang.Float` (default to zero)
- `int and java.lang.Integer` (default to zero)
- `long and java.lang.Long` (default to zero)
- `short and java.lang.Short` (default to zero)
- `java.lang.String` (default to null)
- `java.io.File` (no default value)
- `java.net.URL` (no default value)
- `java.sql.Date` (no default value)
- `java.sql.Time` (no default value)
- `java.sql.Timestamp` (no default value)

You can find a good example in [Convert Utils Demo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/ConvertUtilsDemo.htm) if you need another converter or replace someone.

- [*Registering ConvertUtils*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719645/beanutils-copy-properties-registering-convertutils)