# BeanUtils.setProperty throws exception with value NULL

Tags: java, null, apache-commons-beanutils

I am using org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(bean,name,value).
When the value is NULL it throws an exception .
Digging inside class what is causing the exception is the ConverterUtilsBean.convert method more specifically the BigDecimalConverter.convert that does not accept null.
How can i overcome this issue ?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
ConvertUtilsBean convertUtilsBean = BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().getConvertUtils();
convertUtilsBean.register(false, true, -1);
```

[BeanUtils Copy Properties: Registering ConvertUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719645/beanutils-copy-properties-registering-convertutils)

check this thread out!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).